# Basic SQL user-defined functions, not working properly

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, operator-precedence

I'm trying to write a function in SQL that outputs the winning percentage of a team in a season's worth of baseball.

```
CREATE FUNCTION
calc_winning_percentage(IN w integer, IN l integer, OUT p numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS $$
    SELECT $1 ::numeric/$1 + $2 AS p;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This is the current function. It should be dead simple. W = wins. L = losses. P = percentage. 
You take wins (w) and divide it by wins + losses (w + l). In theory, this gives the winning percentage.

I took some data that was already provided and tried plugging it in. It's close, but it's not right. Let's say we have a team with 96 wins and 63 losses. If you take those two numbers and add them up, you get 159. 96/159 = ~.604. However, when I run those numbers with a query, I get 64.0000.

I'm not this bad at writing functions in other languages (I *promise*), so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_winning_percentage(
     w integer
    ,l integer
    ,OUT p numeric)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
    SELECT $1::numeric / ($1 + $2)
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

You need parentheses around `($1 + $2)`.

#### Round

You can either build it into your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_winning_percentage_rd3(
  w integer, 
  l integer,
  OUT p numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS
$func$
SELECT round($1::numeric/($1 + $2), 3)
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

*Or* you can apply `round()` to the functio from above like this:

```
SELECT round(calc_winning_percentage(1000, 29), 3);
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8630d/2)

Note that [`round()` with two parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) requires `numeric` as 1st input.

Comment: That... would do it. 

As a side, I guess one would use a ROUND function to get it down to three decimal places?

Comment: @AaronMcRuer: Yeah, `round()`. Or cast the result to `numeric(1000,3)`. But rather use `round()`.

Comment: I'm unable to get round to accept the function as an argument.